# Oracle Apex showing different result than SQL Script

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a very weird issue or bug with oracle Apex. I ran a script within Oracle SQL Developer to make sure it was correct. Below is the result

[image]

However if I run the Exact same script in Apex I have missing data (col 3,4,5 example).

[image]

I have ran it in various reports and and even a tabular form also with in Oracle apex. If tried logging out. clearing cache, server cache, restarting server and so on. yet still get the same result.

script

```
SELECT distinct MD.ENG_ID,
E."NAME" as f_name,
E.SURNAME as l_name,
E.POST_CODE||' '||E.TEL_NUMBER Eng_d,
R.ROLE,
RE.SHORTN as Reg,
md."1" as "1d",
l1.MATRIX_DATA  as "1",
md."2" as "2d",
l2.MATRIX_DATA  as "2",
md."3" as "3d",
l3.MATRIX_DATA  as "3",
md."4" as "4d",
l4.MATRIX_DATA  as "4",
md."5" as "5d",
l5.MATRIX_DATA  as "5",
md."6" as "6d",
l6.MATRIX_DATA  as "6",
md."7" as "7d",
l7.MATRIX_DATA  as "7",
md."8" as "8d",
l8.MATRIX_DATA  as "8",
md."9" as "9d",
l9.MATRIX_DATA  as "9",
md."10" as "10d",
l10.MATRIX_DATA  as "10",
md."11" as "11d",
l11.MATRIX_DATA  as "11",
md."12" as "12d",
l12.MATRIX_DATA  as "12",
md."13" as "13d",
l13.MATRIX_DATA  as "13",
md."14" as "14d",
l14.MATRIX_DATA  as "14",
md."15" as "15d",
l15.MATRIX_DATA  as "15",
md."16" as "16d",
l16.MATRIX_DATA  as "16",
md."17" as "17d",
l17.MATRIX_DATA  as "17",
md."18" as "18d",
l18.MATRIX_DATA  as "18",
md."19" as "19d",
l19.MATRIX_DATA  as "19",
md."20" as "20d",
l20.MATRIX_DATA  as "20",
md."21" as "21d",
l21.MATRIX_DATA  as "21",
md."22" as "22d",
l22.MATRIX_DATA  as "22",
md."23" as "23d",
l23.MATRIX_DATA  as "23",
md."24" as "24d",
l24.MATRIX_DATA  as "24",
md."25" as "25d",
l25.MATRIX_DATA  as "25",
md."26" as "26d",
l26.MATRIX_DATA  as "26",
md."27" as "27d",
l27.MATRIX_DATA  as "27",
md."28" as "28d",
l28.MATRIX_DATA  as "28",
md."29" as "29d",
l29.MATRIX_DATA  as "29",
md."30" as "30d",
l30.MATRIX_DATA  as "30",
md."31" as "31d",
l31.MATRIX_DATA  as "31"
 FROM MATRX_DATA_V2 MD 
left join MAN_ENGINEERS E
on E.ENG_ID=MD.ENG_ID
left join ROLE_LOOKUP R
on R.ROLE_ID=md."roles"
left join md_REGION_AREA re
 on RE.ID=MD."Region"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l1
on l1.MD_ID=md."1"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l2
on l2.MD_ID=md."2"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l3
on l3.MD_ID=md."3"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l4
on l4.MD_ID=md."4"  
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l5
on l5.MD_ID=md."5"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l6
 on l6.MD_ID=md."6"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l7
 on l7.MD_ID=md."7"
 left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l8
 on l8.MD_ID=md."8"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l9
on l9.MD_ID=md."9"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l10
on l10.MD_ID=md."10"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l11
 on l11.MD_ID=md."11"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l12
on l12.MD_ID=md."12"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l13
on l13.MD_ID=md."13"  
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l14
on l14.MD_ID=md."14"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l15
on l15.MD_ID=md."15"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l16
on l16.MD_ID=md."16"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l17
on l17.MD_ID=md."17"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l18
on l18.MD_ID=md."18"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l19
on l19.MD_ID=md."19"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l20
on l20.MD_ID=md."20"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l21
on l21.MD_ID=md."21"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l22
on l22.MD_ID=md."22"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l23
on l23.MD_ID=md."23"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l24
on l24.MD_ID=md."24"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l25
on l25.MD_ID=md."25"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l26
on l26.MD_ID=md."26"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l27
on l27.MD_ID=md."27"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l28
on l28.MD_ID=md."28"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l29
on l29.MD_ID=md."29"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l30
on l30.MD_ID=md."30"
left join MATRIX_TRIP_V2 l31
on l31.MD_ID=md."31" 
where E.active = 1 and e.eng_id =7;
```

Comment: Can result of a query depend on user and its access rights? If yes, check first user name in SQL Developer and in Apex (if query runs in `SQL Workshop`, look at schema name at right top corner of a screen).

Comment: both use the same user and access rights and the results are open.

Comment: Do you have uncommitted data in your SQL Developer session, perhaps, particularly in MATRIX_TRIP_V2? Restarting server means what, you bounced the database; and you you ran the query in both clients and still got different results?

Comment: WOW what a school boy error. I've ran the update patch then commited. All fine many thanks.

Comment: Was just going to suggest that and thought "Nah, too silly"!